# Detect Mac OS version with PHP

Tags: php, macos, operating-system, user-agent

I have created a script to detect OS version of windows with the help of the internet, but Now I am stuck at detecting Mac OS versions. I have no Mac OS to test the code and to find out what to use and searching Google did not really help me.
These are the versions I've found on Wiki:[LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Mac_OS)

With Windows I've found for example:
windows nt 6.1 = Windows 7.

```
if (preg_match('/windows nt 6.1/i', $user_agent)) {

            $platform .= ' 7';

        }
```

How to detect the number version of Mac?
This is the only piece I have, but it's not accurate for all versions:

```
if (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $user_agent)) {

    $platform = 'Mac';

} 
    if (preg_match('/mac_powerpc/i', $user_agent)) {

        $platform .= ' OS 9';

    } elseif (preg_match('/macintosh/i', $user_agent)) {

        $platform .= ' OS X';

    }
```

Comment: http://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/2562-php-to-detect-browser-and-operating-system/

Comment: Not my solutions. I already found that before posting my question. It does not say how to detect individual OS version like is it OS9 or OS10 etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want precise results and still go home today switch to UAparser library:
https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-php

From their manual:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use UAParser\Parser;

$ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Ma...";

$parser = Parser::create();
$result = $parser->parse($ua);

print $result->ua->family;            // Safari
print $result->ua->major;             // 6
print $result->ua->minor;             // 0
print $result->ua->patch;             // 2
print $result->ua->toString();        // Safari 6.0.2
print $result->ua->toVersion();       // 6.0.2

print $result->os->family;            // Mac OS X
print $result->os->major;             // 10
print $result->os->minor;             // 7
print $result->os->patch;             // 5
print $result->os->patchMinor;        // [null]
print $result->os->toString();        // Mac OS X 10.7.5
print $result->os->toVersion();       // 10.7.5

print $result->device->family;        // Other

print $result->toString();            // Safari 6.0.2/Mac OS X 10.7.5
print $result->originalUserAgent;     // Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Ma...
```

Use [this](https://packagist.org/packages/ua-parser/uap-php) package if you use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/):

```
"require": { 
    "ua-parser/uap-php": "dev-master"
}
```